# Why does it say that there's a casting error

Tags: c#

I am pretty new to C# and I'm stuck with a problem in the code. Apparently, there is a casting error, can you tell me what is it?

Here's the code

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // side a and b
    Console.WriteLine("Side A of 90° triangle");
    double a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Side B");
    double b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    // c^2
    int csqr = (a * a) + (b * b);
    int hypo = Math.Sqrt(csqr);

    // hypo
    Console.WriteLine("hypotenuse:-  " + hypo);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact error that you're seeing.

Comment: ask yourself how opeartions on double may result in int.. and how an int could  be appended to a string

Comment: double to int cannot performed implicitly. You must cast the result to int or keep double, which seems better to me.

Comment: Sidenote: **Never** trust user input. Using `Convert.ToDouble` directly on `Console.ReadLine()` will throw an exception if your user enters anything that can't be converted to a double. Instead, you should use `TryParse` that will only return false if the value can't be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a double into an int. Variables hypo csqr must be double.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       //side a and b
       Console.WriteLine("Side A of 90° triangle");
       double a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
       Console.WriteLine("Side B");
       double b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
       //c^2
       double csqr = (a * a) + (b * b);
       double hypo = Math.Sqrt(csqr);
       //hypo
       Console.WriteLine("hypotenuse:-  " + hypo);
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

The variables csqr and hypo should be of type double while you defined them as int.
Sqrt is a method to find the square root. thus it takes a parameter of type double and returns double.
[sqrt documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=net-6.0)

csqr variable should be of type double because of the arithmetic operations on a double operands.